# How to write JSON from response to file? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

so im trying to write this JSON from the [Kik smiley](https://sticker-service.appspot.com/v2/collection/smiley) site, and im trying to do this so I wont have to write it manually, anyways I need to parse the JSON so only some of the existing JSON shows up in the file (basically cleaning it) what I need from the site is... (name, id, type) how would I do this?

I have written this in python but it seems to fail, and im not 100% sure as to why. I am new to Python, so sorry if this is an obvious question! I did find something earlier but it just confused me even more :) Thank you!

```
import requests, json, sys

from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored

#colorama
init()
class SmileyGrabber():

    def __init__(self):
        # requests vars
        self.smileysFound = 0
        self.smileysLost = 0
        self.url="https://sticker-service.appspot.com/v2/collection/smiley"
        self.session = requests.Session()

        self.grabSmiley()

    def grabSmiley(self):
        while True:
            try:
                r = self.session.get(self.url)
                j = r.json()
                try:
                    if j["IsSuccess"] == True:
                        meta = j["smileys"]
                        sID = meta["id"]
                        sType = meta["type"]
                        sName = meta["name"]
                        FormatSmileyData(sID, sType, sName)
                        print "Smiley Found:", colored("({0})".format(sName), "cyan")
                        self.smileysFound += 1
                    else:
                        print(colored("Could not grab smiley"), "red")
                        self.smileysLost += 1
                except:
                    sys.exit()

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                sys.exit()

            except:
                print r.text
                sys.exit()


class FormatSmileyData(object):
    def __init__(self, sID, sType, sName):
        smileyData = {}
        data = []
        data.append({"SMILEY_ID":sID, "SMILEY_TYPE":sType, "SMILEY_NAME":sName})

        dataFile = open("smileys.json", "a+")
        dataFile.write(json.dumps(smileyData)+"\n")
        dataFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SmileyGrabber()
```

Comment: By "it seems to fail" does it generate an invalid file, or throw an error, or what specifically? Can you include the error you get?

Comment: the file is not made, all it does is print r.text

Comment: I think you want `dataFile.write(json.dumps(data[0])+"\n")` ... also why do you have it in a `try/except` like that

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

1. It will be more efficient to read from the network all at once
   rather than making a call to session.get for each smiley.
2. j does not have an `"IsSuccess"` element, so that will never be true
3. `j["smileys"]` is a list, so to get the dictionaries (which represent each smiley) you will need to iterate through that list.
4. You are appending data into `data` but you are writing from
   `smileyData`, which never has any data entered into it.
5. Each time you call the `FormatSmileyData` constructor, you are
   resetting the data.

Take a look at a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to prettify the JSON so you can see the structure.  This can help figure out how to parse it.

Here's an updated version of your script that appears to work:
I removed the colorization and made it work with Python 3.

```
import requests, json, sys

class SmileyGrabber():

    def __init__(self):
        # requests vars
        self.smileysFound = 0
        self.smileysLost = 0
        self.url="https://sticker-service.appspot.com/v2/collection/smiley"
        self.session = requests.Session()

        self.data = []

        self.grabSmiley()
        self.writeSmileyData()

    def grabSmiley(self):
        r = self.session.get(self.url)
        j = r.json()
        print ("got json")
        print (str(len(j)))
        for element in j:
            for meta in element["smileys"]:
                print ("---------------")
                print (str(meta))
                sID = meta["id"]
                sType = meta["type"]
                sName = meta["name"]
                self.addSmileyData(sID, sType, sName)
                print ("Smiley Found:" + "({0})".format(sName))
                self.smileysFound += 1
                print ("found " + str(self.smileysFound))
        else:
            print("Could not grab smiley")
            self.smileysLost += 1


    def addSmileyData(self, sID, sType, sName):
        self.data.append({"SMILEY_ID":sID, "SMILEY_TYPE":sType, "SMILEY_NAME":sName})

    def writeSmileyData(self):
        dataFile = open("smileys.json", "a+")
        dataFile.write(json.dumps(self.data)+"\n")
        dataFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SmileyGrabber()
```